# Pass dispatch function to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm developing a universal react application using redux. in my action creators I dispatch my data to store.

in ComponentDidMount function dispatch function is Ok but when I want pass it to component in render function It gives me error that **Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined**
How I can pass my dispatch functions to component?

Container Code :

```
class DealContainer extends React.Component {
static readyOnActions(dispatch, params) {
                return Promise.all([
                    dispatch(DealsActions.fetchDealData(params.id)),
                    dispatch(SubmitActions.fetchSubmitInitialData()),

                ]);
            }

            componentDidMount() {
                DealContainer.readyOnActions(this.props.dispatch,this.props.params);

            }
    render() {
    return(
    <MyComponent 
    changeStoreFunction = {this.props.dispatch(SubmitActions.changeUserId)}
    />)

    }
    const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
        return {
            dealData: state.dealData,
            routing: ownProps.location.query,
            submitInitialData: state.submitInitialData,
            id: ownProps.params.id,
            mapInfo: state.mapInfo,
            areaList: state.areaList,
        }
    };

    DealContainer.propTypes = {
        params: PropTypes.shape({
            id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        }).isRequired,
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };
        }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DealContainer);
```

Comment: whers is your `mapDispatchToProps` ?

Comment: @AkashShinde I use propTypes

Comment: even though you need to define `mapDispatchToProps` function to access dispatch from react root context

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you need to use mapDispatchToProps to get access to the dispatch function.

There you can define your function that will be called within your component render method :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    yourFunctionToCallFromComponent: () => {
      dispatch(yourAction())
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DealContainer);
```

Comment: @SepEhr if this answer helped you, please tick it as an answer that solved your problem/question :) thanks